# SSI's work for .asp pages, but not for .html pages

Tags: html, ssi

I have an IIS server with several test websites on it, for internal development. On one site, a .asp page will execute the ssi;   I've copied the .asp page to a .html page, and the ssi does *not* execute.  What can I check to see why the ssi fails for .html pages?
I inherited the task of updating web pages on our current website; using the test server, I noticed that the header & footer of .html pages weren't appearing - but there was directory of only .asp pages, and the server side includes all worked fine.
When I copied an "index.html" page to "index.asp" in the main directory, the .html page didn't show the SSI, while the .asp page did.  The two were identical aside from the file extension.

Comment: I'm using Server Manager 10.

Comment: Googling `iis enable ssi html` finds me a few results that seem to apply, so please try that (or try harder) next time...